# Updating a many-to-many relationship in Prisma

Tags: prisma

I'm trying to figure out the right way to implement an upsert/update of the following schema:

```prisma
model Post {
  author      String     @Id
  lastUpdated DateTime   @default(now())
  categories  Category[]
}

model Category {
  id     Int     @id
  posts  Post[]
}
```

Here is what I'd like to do. Get a post with category ids attached to it and insert it into the schema above.

The following command appears to insert the post

```js
const post = await prisma.post.upsert({
  where:{
    author: 'TK'
  },
  update:{
    lastUpdated: new Date()
  },
  create: {
    author: 'TK'
  }
})
```

My challenge is how do I also upsert the Category. I'll be getting a list of Catogories in the like 1,2,3 and if they do not exist I need to insert it into the category table and add the post to it. If the category does exist, I need to update the record with the post I inserted above preserving all attached posts.

Would appreciate it if I could be pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the model, it can be simplified as follows as Prisma supports `@updatedAt` which will automatically update the column:

```
model Post {
  author      String     @id
  lastUpdated DateTime   @updatedAt
  categories  Category[]
}

model Category {
  id    Int    @id
  posts Post[]
}
```

As for the query, it would look like this:

```js
const categories = [
  { create: { id: 1 }, where: { id: 1 } },
  { create: { id: 2 }, where: { id: 2 } },
]
await db.post.upsert({
  where: { author: 'author' },
  create: {
    author: 'author',
    categories: {
      connectOrCreate: categories,
    },
  },
  update: {
    categories: { connectOrCreate: categories },
  },
})
```

[connectOrCreate](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries#nested-writes) will create if not present and add the categories to the posts as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That code works, however, when I do an upsert with the same categoeries but a different author, a findMany() query will throw a panic.

    const posts = await prisma.post.findMany(
        {include: {categories:true}}); 

Using prisma studio to query the post table will also fail because of this. I'm trying to understand what is causing the failure but its not readily apparent to me.

Comment: Had to modify the Category table with an additional field:
`lastUpdated DateTime   @updatedAt` to get this to work. Seems like you need another field for the findMany() query to work in a many to many relationship