# How to create or update many-to-many relation in Prisma?

Tags: sql, many-to-many, prisma

I have the following models, and many-to-many relation between them:

```sql
model User {
  id            String    @id @default(cuid())
  name          String?
  email         String?   @unique
  followings    Artist[]
}

model Artist {
  id           String @id @default(cuid())
  name         String @unique
  spotifyId    String @unique
  followers    User[]
}
```

When a user logs into my app, I retrieve their current followed artists, and need to update my database.

I have managed to select artists data from database (for updating user <-> artist relation), sample data:

```json
const followings = [
  {
    id: '...',
    name: 'MARINA',
    spotifyId: '6CwfuxIqcltXDGjfZsMd9A'
  },
  {
    id: '...',
    name: 'Dua Lipa',
    spotifyId: '6M2wZ9GZgrQXHCFfjv46we'
  },
]
```

Now, this is my user object:

```js
const user = {
  id: 'someId',
  name: 'someName',
  email: 'someEmail'
}
```

I tried to insert or update user <-> artist relation with this query but I'm getting `Bad Request` error:

```
await prisma.user.upsert({
    where: {
        email: user.email
    },
    create: {
        name: user.name,
        email: user.email,
        followings: {
            connectOrCreate: followings
        }
    },
    update: {
        followings: {
            connectOrCreate: followings
        }
    }
})
```

Please advise what I need to do. Thanks in advance.

P.S. I took the idea of the query from [Updating a many-to-many relationship in Prisma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65587200/updating-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-prisma) post, but it didn't work for me, so please don't mark duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`connectOrCreate` should specify `where` key with id (so Prisma could find this entity) and `create` key with all required model fields (so Prisma could create it if it not already present), but you just passing an array of models. Change your code to this one:

```
  await prisma.user.upsert({
    where: {
      email: 'user.email',
    },
    create: {
      name: 'user.name',
      email: 'user.email',
      followings: {
        connectOrCreate: [
          {
            create: {
              name: 'MARINA',
              spotifyId: '6CwfuxIqcltXDGjfZsMd9A',
            },
            where: { id: '...' },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
    update: {
      followings: {
        connectOrCreate: [
          {
            create: {
              name: 'MARINA',
              spotifyId: '6CwfuxIqcltXDGjfZsMd9A',
            },
            where: { id: '...' },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  });
```